# Progressing through levels as you reach a goal

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a game where I want the player to progress to the next level as he reaches the goal. This is the current code I am using to load the scene titled Level2:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Level2");
```

I can get the second level to load but for some reason the first level loads with it. Is there a piece of code I need to use that clears out level 1?

Answer (score 1):

By researhing a little further I found that this can be fixed by adding:

```
LoadSceneMode.Single
```

So the final code looks like:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Level2", LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

However, I am still wondering if there is a better way to do this. Im still messing around with

```
AssetBundle.LoadFromFile
```

This could be a better approach. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: The [default for that method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) (i.e. without that second parameter) *is* `LoadSceneMode.Single`. But if specifying it explicitly fixes a problem you have, then...that's fine.

Comment: Pb is elsewhere. You did two things, that addition and smg else. That else fixed ur pb. Probably adding the scene to build or fixing the name in the merhod.

Comment: Yes, I did add the scene to the build